How to distinguish between but-1-ene and but-2-ene?
I noticed that the substances but-1-ene and but-2-ene have quite similar physical and chemical properties. So I wonder that how they can be distinguished?

The 1H NMR spectra are quite different

"quite similar" lacks a reference/a scale to compare to, and the question is a bit too general about physical properties. See for instance the melting points of $\pu{−185.3 °C}$ (1-butene), $\pu{−138.9 °C}$ (cis-but-2-ene) and $\pu{-105.5 °C}$ (trans-but-2-ene, common reference).
